# What is this structure / method called?

Tags: php, html, methods, structure

I have been using this file structure for a while now and I'm not sure where I got the idea from (possibly PHPBB? Maybe Wordpress?)

Basically, I create a page, like `index.php`.  Inside of the index, I use php to `require_once` the head/meta information (which I call meta.php).  Inside this meta.php, I include all global scripts and style sheets, along with anything else, like viewports, that a page would need.

then I close the head section in the index.php which allows me to add any specific links, like specific CSS or specific javascript and also allows me to change the title of the page if necessary.

After I close the head, I start the `<body>` and give it an `id` with the name of the page (You will see in the example below).

After I open the body, I include the header, which is global and has the navigation and site identity.

Then I include the content of the page which is in another directory

Then I include the footer which also has the end `</body></html>` tags in it.

Here's an example of my index.php:

```
<?PHP 
    $currentFile = explode("/", $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); //Get the current URL name
    $fileName = end($currentFile); //Get the current File name
    $baseName = explode(".", $fileName); //Get the name without .php
    require_once('global/meta.php'); //Include the meta information
?>
    <!-- Add extra scripts and meta information per page here -->
    <title>Custom Page Title</title>
</head>
<!-- Change the ID to whatever the page is called to allow for the right navigation to show as active -->
<body id="<?= $baseName ?>"> 
<?PHP
    require_once('global/header.php'); //This is the end of the header
    require_once("pages/" . $baseName[0] . "/" . $fileName); //This is the content of the page
    require_once('global/footer.php'); //This is the footer of this page
?>
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
/global/
    /images/
    /scripts/
    /styles/
    footer.php
    header.php
    meta.php
/pages/
    /index/
        /images/
        /scripts/
        /styles/
        index.php
index.php
```

I'm trying to find out what this file structure or method is called.  This is not an MVC framework, right?  Is this called anything and does anyone see many problems with this?

Comment: You're correct that it's not MVC. Using a require statement is simply including another file. Not sure if people call it anything but just that.

Comment: I see.  Would you think this could be an accepted method of development?

Comment: MVC framework = model, view, controller. For example you'd have a Pages controller, maybe a user model which is used to log in a user and certain pages may access this model to determine if the user has sufficient permission, and all data would be passed into the view. I believe most seasoned programmers use the MVC concept or at least at a minimum separate your controlling code from your view via a templating engine like [smarty](http://smarty.net) or [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)

Comment: Here is a really good tutorial which explains the idea behind MVC: http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/ - ultimately separating your controlling code from your objects from your actual design/view makes it very easy to scale & update in the long run though.